# Javascript variable... can't reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone tells me why this reference doesn't work?

```
var a_nav_href = $(this).attr("data-id"); //get the id data when click in a tag**strong text**
$(".wrapper").find("section[id=a_nav_href]").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You have written:

```
var a_nav_href = $(this).attr("data-id"); 
$(".wrapper").find("section[id=a_nav_href]").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

In this code snippet **"a_nav_href"** is part of selector but as a string. You need to append the value of a_nav_href tot he selector.

Replace it with

```
$(".wrapper").find("section[id=" + a_nav_href + "]").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

This will return a selector query looking like this

```
$(".wrapper").find("section[id=someIDWhichIWantToSearch]").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot...I did it!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks for `id=a_nav_href`

You want:

```
$(".wrapper").find("section[id=" + a_nav_href + "]").css({"background-color": "red"});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you made my day! @Tomasz Jakub Rup